# How to take the limit of a complex function as $|z|$ goes to infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

While I do not now how to make sense of the following in general

$$\lim\limits_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}f(z) $$

I would specifically like to find

$$ \lim\limits_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}e^{iaz^2}$$

where $a$ is a positive integer and $0 < arg \; z \leq \pi /4$.

I thought about considering $e^{iar^2e^{i\theta}}$, and taking the limit as $r\rightarrow \infty$, but I couldn't make sense of that either.

**Edit:** added the constraint on $argz$ that I initially forgot.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{\lvert z\rvert\to\infty} e^{iaz^2}$ doesn't exist. $\infty$ is an essential singularity of that function, and the limit only exists if $\infty$ is a pole or a removable singularity.

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Methods-Physics-Engineering-Comprehensive/dp/0521679710) claims that this limit is $0$. (Chapter $24$, exercise $10$)

Comment: If that's really what the book claims, then the book is wrong.  Consider the case where $z^2 = -it$ with $t > 0$.

Comment: I have discovered that I overlooked a piece of information: $0 < arg z \leq \pi /4$. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier to use a transformation such as $w = 1/z$.  Then 
$\lim_{|z| \to \infty} f(z) = \lim_{w \to 0} f(1/w)$.  Of course as Daniel Fischer noted, in this case you have an essential singularity and the limit does not exist.

Comment: I don't quite understand how setting $w=1/z$ converts $|z| \rightarrow \infty$ to $w \rightarrow 0$. How do we get rid of the modulus?

Comment: $|w|\to 0$ and $w\to 0$ are the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

If $0< \arg(z)\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $0< \arg(z^2)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$. This means that $z^2=x+iy$ with $x\geq0$ and $y>0$. Thus $$\vert e^{iaz^2}\vert=\vert e^{iax}\vert\vert e^{-ay}\vert=e^{-ay}$$

We see that $e^{-ay}\to0$ as $y\to+\infty$. If you take $z$ to $\infty$ in such a way that $y\to\infty$, then you will get your desired result.

But without another condition on the problem, I can make $y\to0$ as $z\to\infty$ by taking the path $z^2=t+\frac{i}{t-1}$ for $t\geq 0$.

If you take $z$ to $\infty$ in such a way that $z^2$ goes to $\infty$ radially, say along a line $y=mx$, then $z^2=(\frac{1}{m}+i)y$ and $\vert z\vert\to\infty$ gives $\vert y\vert\to\infty$.